# Is there a word for scrambling lyrics because the melody is repeated?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm a huge fan of the musical Les Miserables. Oftentimes I will find myself absentmindedly singing songs from the musical while I'm doing mindless tasks like cleaning. Since certain melody phrases repeat often in the musical, sometimes I will start a song and then suddenly switch songs, even characters, mid-phrase, without skipping a beat, and often without even realizing it.

For example: *Valjean:* That nothing remains but the cry of my hate?
The cries in the dark that nobody hears?
Here where I stand at the turning of the years.
If there's another way to go/
I missed it twenty long years ago (...morph...)
*Javert:* I am the Law and the Law is not mocked!
I'll spit his pity right back in his face!
There is nothing on earth that we share/
It is either Valjean or Javert!

Does this phenomenon have a name? If not a specific name, is there a good word for it? I'd accept a good, descriptive phrase too.

Pretty much the same thing can happen with poetry too, especially if it is particularly rhythmic. So if there is a word or phrase for that, it might work here too.

*BTW That particular example is pretty deep. If you know the musical (or even better, the novel), that those two particular songs flow together so easily is brilliant. Kudos to Alain Boublil, Claude-Michel Schonberg and Herbert Kretzmer.*

Comment: [music.se] knows?

Comment: I don't think there's any established word or phrase for this. You could use something like: *singing a hodgepodge of songs*, *music mash*, *song mix-n-match*, *lyrical chimera*, ...

Comment: @Kris I was thinking that. I'll try there in a few days if I don't get an answer here that works for me.

Comment: [*meta*] Could be migrated to [music.se]

Comment: @Kris I'd really rather not migrate it, at least not yet. I'd like to find a way to express the phenomenon in standard English. I'm really not looking for any kind of technical term.

Comment: My "accidental medleys" sometimes get a little weird and dark - I'll start out humming an old hymn from my childhood: "We gather together to ask the Lord's blessing"; then it morphs into *Streets of Laredo*: "So beat the drum slowly and play the fife lowly"; finally it turns into the scary proto-Nazi anthem from *Cabaret*: "Tomorrow belongs to me!"  This usually goes on for a few verses' time before I notice, and it sorta creeps me out when I do notice...

Comment: I think our musical wanderings are not unlike word association games, in that what ultimately gets spliced together might be dependent on such factors as explicit and implicit cues in the words or harmony, long-term and short-term memory, emotions, and *creativity* (I know, kind of vague). I doubt we are anywhere close to fully understanding these neural happenings, though this is an attempt: http://www.peabody.jhu.edu/past_issues/fall08/the_science_of_improv.html

Comment: @Sel The link is broken, but I think I agree with what you're saying. Certainly my mix-ups *feel* spontaneous and random, but it's remarkable how much sense they make.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp It would would require a bit of explanation, but I kind of like "lyrical chimera" for my purpose

Comment: @MT_Head: I've got a weird one like that too, dark and light: I start off with the "Imperial March" from *Star Wars* and sometimes somehow segue into "A Spoonful of Sugar" from *Mary Poppins*.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are spontaneously splitting and joining different musical segments. Using musical terminology, this is a type of **[improvisation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/improvise)**.

> 1 To compose, recite, play, or sing extemporaneously
>
> 2 To make, invent, or arrange offhand

If you sometimes repeat a musical phrase in altered form, then you are improvising a [**variation**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/variation).

> The repetition of a musical theme with modifications in such
> elements as rhythm, melody, harmony, key, tempo, and accompaniment

Furthermore, you could you call your activity an [**arrangement**](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrangement_%28music%29) of the original songs, because you are collapsing an orchestral score to a solo voice.

> An arrangement of a musical composition is a reworking of a piece of music so that it can be played by a different instrument or combination of instruments from the original.

Finally, you are composing a **[medley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medley_%28music%29)**, and since I am a Les Miserables fan myself, here is a [video example for your enjoyment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9IWAxSpgKA).

> In music, a medley is a piece composed from parts of existing pieces, usually three, played one after another, sometimes overlapping.

Comment: "Spontaneously splitting and joining different musical segments" is a pretty good description in itself. I don't think improvisation or variation work because they imply intent.

Comment: Hmm, musical improvisation is by definition extemporaneous, though I agree that it hints at a more focused, deliberate activity, as opposed to "random" singing.

Comment: The randomness is kind of key here. I have several phrases from that musical that I frequently juxtapose, completely mindlessly. But, like the example in the OP, meaning can be found in the juxtaposition. I credit the writers, and am looking to more effectively express my appreciation. *if that makes any sense*

Answer (score 1):

This phenomenon is known as a "Mondegreen".  The etymology is from a classic case in point, where the hearer reportedly construed a couple of lines from an old ballad incorrectly.
The actual words are along the lines of "They've slain the Earl of Murray, and laid [sic] him on the Green . . .".  This was reportedly construed as "They've slain the Earl of Murray and Lady Mondegreen."

I'm not making this up!

Comment: Why did you sic “laid him”?

Comment: Love the word, but it's not quite the same thing. A mondegreen is a "mishearing or misinterpretation of a phrase as a result of near-homophony" - from Wiki. There is no misunderstanding in the phenomenon of the OP.